# Remove outliers from plot in lattice (splom)

Tags: r, lattice, outliers

I'd like to plot some data as a scatter plot matrix with lattice. However, the data contains some outliers. This leads to a very squeezed plot of the main data. I'd like to remove the outliers from the plots. An observation can be an outlier for one measured variable, but not for another, so a computation of the outliers that are to be removed is required for every single scatter plot within the matrix. As the outliers constitute maximal 10 observations out of around 10,000 I was thinking of simply removing the 10 observations with the lowest value for each variable (the outliers are usually those in the more negative direction). I know that I have to modify the panel function, but I'm stuck with how to do this. In addition, my lower panel is a hexbinplot, so it should be modified as well, and I hope that this would work the same way. Does anyone have an idea?

MWE:

```
require(lattice)
require(hexbin)
data(iris)

iris.out <- iris
iris.out[2,1] <- 1
iris.out[3,1] <- .2
iris.out[4,2] <- .1
iris.out[5,2] <- .2

splom(~iris.out[1:4], groups = Species, data = iris,
  lower.panel = function(...,groups){
    panel.hexbinplot(xbins = 20,
                     colramp = function(n){heat.ob(n, beg=15, end=225)},...,groups=NULL)
  },
  diag.panel = function(x,...){
    yrng <- current.panel.limits()$ylim
    d <- density(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    d$y <- with(d, yrng[1] + 0.95 * diff(yrng) * y / max(y))
    panel.lines(d, col = "darkgrey")
    diag.panel.splom(x, ...)
  }
```

)

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution perhaps. For the bivariate plots, I removed outliers, as defined by the lowest 10 observed values, in both x and y. Also, the 'groups' factor is only implemented in the upper panel.

```
splom(~iris.out[1:4],
  lower.panel=function(x,y,...){
    x.out=order(x,decreasing=FALSE)[1:10]
    y.out=order(x,decreasing=FALSE)[1:10]
    out=c(x.out,y.out)
    x=x[-out]
    y=y[-out]
    panel.hexbinplot(x,y, xbins =20,colramp = function(n){heat.ob(n, beg=15, end=225)},...)
  },
  diag.panel = function(x,...){
    x=x[-order(x,decreasing=FALSE)[1:10]]
    yrng <- current.panel.limits()$ylim
    d <- density(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    d$y <- with(d, yrng[1] + 0.95 * diff(yrng) * y / max(y))
    panel.lines(d, col = "darkgrey")
    diag.panel.splom(x, ...)
  },
  upper.panel=function(x,y,groups=iris$Species,...){
    x.out=order(x,decreasing=FALSE)[1:10]
    y.out=order(x,decreasing=FALSE)[1:10]
    out=c(x.out,y.out)
    x=x[-out]
    y=y[-out]
    panel.splom(x,y,groups=iris$Species,...)
  }
)
```